# Emualtor not attached Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying to attach the emulator to Android studio but it doesn't appear on the list of devices. I've tried to execute it from the run button and avd manager.

Besides I've checked and uncheked the Tools > Android > Enable ADB integration option but it doesn't work. Trying to execute adb kill-server and adb-start server it doesn't work neither.

Finally I've tried to start the emulator from terminal by exececuting emulator @name_of_device

Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

But then when I execute adb devices, the list of devices attached is empty

Does anybody how to solve this?

Comment: do u have two separate instances of adb running?? one for android studio and one for emulator?

Comment: No, I've already checked it.

Comment: u found any solution?

Comment: No, I've tested it on Windows 10  and on OS X and it doesn't work. It seems very strange to me that nobody else have complained about this problem.